# Actionscript button bar not showing Hebrew letters

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I've declared a bindable array like this:

```
[Bindable]
var lettersDS:Array = new Array('#','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','א','ב','ג','ד','ה','ו','ז','ח','ט','י','כ','ל','מ','נ','ס','ע','פ','צ','ק','ר','ש','ת');
```

As you can see, the array inludes the English Alphabet as well as the Hebrew one.

in the MXML I've declared a ButtonBar that uses the above array as a datasource:

```
<s:ButtonBar id="btnBar" color="black" click="btnBar_clickHandler(event)" height="100%" buttonMode="true" chromeColor="{Constants.FontColor}" textAlign="center" width="100%" skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.ButtonBarSkin">
                            <s:layout>
                                <s:VerticalLayout gap="-1" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" />
                            </s:layout>
                            <s:dataProvider>
                                <s:ArrayList source="{lettersDS}" />
                            </s:dataProvider>
</s:ButtonBar>
```

However, when it runs only the English letters are displayed in the buttons, the Hebrew ones are not (their buttons have no labels, they are empty).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Emeleme

Comment: You have a single font set that includes English and Hebrew letters? Otherwise you are going to have to assign different fonts dynamically to each button as it is rendered, you would either have to create a custom Spark Item render or maybe do it through a custom SparkSkin.

Comment: Thanks Robert, The thing is that all over the app I am using a combination of these languages, using the default font set. If I assign this to a grid's datasource for instance, it shows up fine.

Comment: Ok, I did not originally see the skinClass assignment, try removing skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.ButtonBarSkin" and see if the characters show up correctly. They do for me, but that is just a quick test on a Mac, I did not test it on an actual mobile device. Also I am using Air/Flash 19 and Flex 4.14.1

Comment: Hi, Thanks, But no, removing the skinClass did not help. Using Air 19 and Flex 4.14.1 as you are.. :-(

Comment: Works for me as well. I'd guess this is something font related. Are you sure you don't have any other fonts specified for the Button component or some character restrictions ?

Comment: No, just a boiler-plate MXML Air project via the Idea IDE (on OS-X) and I cut/pasted the code from your question minus the skinClass assignment

Comment: Thanks Philarmon, where to look? (I am reffering to Air on Mobile [Android]).